# LaTeXcompilation error regarding Unicode char while building documentation

Tags: doxygen

While compiling a documentation for my c-program, doxygen runs through smooth.
and builds the HTML documentation as desired. But while building PDF document from latex, it gives following error at many places ....

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

my doxygen configuration settings for latex are as shown below,

```html
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If the GENERATE_LATEX tag is set to YES (the default) Doxygen will 
# generate Latex output.

GENERATE_LATEX         = YES

# The LATEX_OUTPUT tag is used to specify where the LaTeX docs will be put. 
# If a relative path is entered the value of OUTPUT_DIRECTORY will be 
# put in front of it. If left blank `latex' will be used as the default path.

LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex

# The LATEX_CMD_NAME tag can be used to specify the LaTeX command name to be 
# invoked. If left blank `latex' will be used as the default command name. 
# Note that when enabling USE_PDFLATEX this option is only used for 
# generating bitmaps for formulas in the HTML output, but not in the 
# Makefile that is written to the output directory.

LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex

# The MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME tag can be used to specify the command name to 
# generate index for LaTeX. If left blank `makeindex' will be used as the 
# default command name.

MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex

# If the COMPACT_LATEX tag is set to YES Doxygen generates more compact 
# LaTeX documents. This may be useful for small projects and may help to 
# save some trees in general.

COMPACT_LATEX          = NO

# The PAPER_TYPE tag can be used to set the paper type that is used 
# by the printer. Possible values are: a4, letter, legal and 
# executive. If left blank a4wide will be used.

PAPER_TYPE             = a4

# The EXTRA_PACKAGES tag can be to specify one or more names of LaTeX 
# packages that should be included in the LaTeX output.

EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 

# The LATEX_HEADER tag can be used to specify a personal LaTeX header for 
# the generated latex document. The header should contain everything until 
# the first chapter. If it is left blank doxygen will generate a 
# standard header. Notice: only use this tag if you know what you are doing!

LATEX_HEADER           = 

# The LATEX_FOOTER tag can be used to specify a personal LaTeX footer for 
# the generated latex document. The footer should contain everything after 
# the last chapter. If it is left blank doxygen will generate a 
# standard footer. Notice: only use this tag if you know what you are doing!

LATEX_FOOTER           = 

# If the PDF_HYPERLINKS tag is set to YES, the LaTeX that is generated 
# is prepared for conversion to pdf (using ps2pdf). The pdf file will 
# contain links (just like the HTML output) instead of page references 
# This makes the output suitable for online browsing using a pdf viewer.

PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES

# If the USE_PDFLATEX tag is set to YES, pdflatex will be used instead of 
# plain latex in the generated Makefile. Set this option to YES to get a 
# higher quality PDF documentation.

USE_PDFLATEX           = YES

# If the LATEX_BATCHMODE tag is set to YES, doxygen will add the \\batchmode. 
# command to the generated LaTeX files. This will instruct LaTeX to keep 
# running if errors occur, instead of asking the user for help. 
# This option is also used when generating formulas in HTML.

LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO

# If LATEX_HIDE_INDICES is set to YES then doxygen will not 
# include the index chapters (such as File Index, Compound Index, etc.) 
# in the output.

LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO

# If LATEX_SOURCE_CODE is set to YES then doxygen will include 
# source code with syntax highlighting in the LaTeX output. 
# Note that which sources are shown also depends on other settings 
# such as SOURCE_BROWSER.

LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
```

how to solve this problem?

If I ignore these errors and go ahead with compilation, it generates TOC but without page numbers!!!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you share and example where it goes wrong?

Comment: sorry for delayed response.....

Comment: version is doxygen v1.7.4

Comment: Would be useful to try 1.8.9.1 as since 1.7.4 (release date 28-03-2011) quite a bit changed.

Comment: Would still be useful to hear whether or not you solved the problem and when not what the results would be with the current version of doxygen (1.8.14). In case in the last version there is still a problem please attach a small example with which we can reproduce the problem.